# jQuery - Concatenate string with integer to create pre-existing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So let's say that I have a variable, slide1.

`var slide1 = $('#slide1');`

How can I concatenate a string, such as 'slide,' with an integer to make it equal to and behave just like that above variable, slide1?

`showThis('slide' + 1);`

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70efo8nt/2/), so you can see a shortened version of my issue/confusion in action. As you'll see, the result of the concatenation is not hiding as I would expect.

Am I attempting to do something completely taboo?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `showThis()` function requires a Jquery object and what you are providing is a string. So your code should actually be this

`showThis($('#slide' + 1));`

Comment: Your answer makes the most sense for what I'm trying to accomplish. My actual full code is using an index variable rather than a static integer (1) that would need to match up with each respective slide id. So thank you! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
var slide1 = $('#slide1');
var button = $('#button');

button.click(function() {
  showThis('slide' + 1);
});

function showThis(thisSlide) {
  alert(thisSlide);
  $("#" + thisSlide).hide();
}
```

Comment: This seems to work for my case. What exactly is the $("#" + thisSlide) part doing?

Comment: The jquery $ expects a string as input, so it just generates a string '#slide1' and ignores your variable previously created. The only difference is that its a dynamic code, not depending on the button you click to work. In this case, as there isnt other buttons, $('#slide1').hide() would be the same

Comment: Oh, so it's not actually relaying back to the variable, just the ID element itself. Not exactly what I need in the long run after all. Thank you!

Comment: Mike Corcoran's answer is what you are looking for, but using window[] to access a variable isn't a good practice

Answer (score 1):

you need to index into the global window object if you really want to do it this way.

```
var slide1 = $('#slide1');
var button = $('#button');

button.click(function() {
  showThis(window['slide' + 1]);
});

function showThis(thisSlide) {
  alert(thisSlide);
  $(thisSlide).hide();
}
```

however i would go with an array like the other posters have responded with

Answer (score 0):

You can access properties of an object with strings, but not really variables.
Like, you have an object

```
var slide = {
  slide1: $('#slide1'),
  var button = $('#button'),
}
```

You could access slide1 with a string like this

```
showThis(slide['slide'+1]);
```

The way you are trying isn't a valid way to access variables.

Answer (score -1):

Any reason you can't use an array? eg:

```
var slides = [];
slides[0] = $('#slide0');
slides[1] = $('#slide1');
//etc
showThis(slides[1]);
```

or even:

```
var slides = [];
for(var i = 0; i< 10; i++){
    slides[i] = $('#slide' + i);
}
showThis(slides[1]);
```